# Need a regex that finds "string" but not "[string]"

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression that parses a string and skips things in brackets.

Something like

```
string = "A bc defg hi [hi] jkl mnop.";
```

The .match() should return "hi" but not [hi].  I've spent 5 hours running through RE's but I'm throwing in the towel.

Also this is for javascript or jquery if that matters.

Any help is appreciated.  Also I'm working on getting my questions formatted correctly : )

EDIT:

Ok I just had a eureka moment and figured out that the original RegExp I was using actually did work.  But when I was replaces the matches with the [matches] it simply replaced the first match in the string... over and over.  I thought this was my regex refusing to skip the brackets but after much time of trying almost all of the solutions below, I realized that I was derping Hardcore.

When .replace was working its magic it was on the first match, so I quite simply added a space to the end of the result word as follows:

```
var result = string.match(regex);
var modifiedResult = '[' + result[0].toString() + ']';
string.replace(result[0].toString() + ' ', modifiedResult + ' ');
```

This got it to stop targeting the original word in the string and stop adding a new set of brackets to it with every match.  Thank you all for your help.  I am going to give answer credit to the post that prodded me in the right direction.

Comment: So do you also want to ignore this case `[other hi other]`?

Comment: Please be more specific. Your delimiters are whitespace? Is the content only alpha characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need regex for this. Simply use string manipulation:

```
var arr = string.split("[");
var final = arr[0] + arr[1].split("]")[1];
```

If there are multiple bracketed expressions, use a loop:

```
while (string.indexOf("[") != -1){
    var arr = string.split("[");
    string = arr[0] + arr.slice(1).join("[").split("]").slice(1).join("]");
}
```

Comment: I think this is on the right track.  Perhaps a bit more information is needed.
I am parsing a string as it is entered on keyup.  The regex I have looks for keywords and adds [brackets] to the match then replaces the keywords in the string real time.  Thus my results end in a loop of bracket addition with each keystroke.
Once it finds 'hi', it turns it into "[hi]" and with every keystroke adds brackets to "[[[[[[hi]]]]]]"

Comment: @Hewhoshallnotbenamed In that case, a simple regex approach would be to replace all instances of `([^\[])yourterm([^\]])` with `$1[yourterm]$2`

Answer (score 3):

preprocess the target string by removing everything between brackets before trying to match your RE

```
string = "A bc defg hi [hi] jkl mnop."
tmpstring = string.replace(/\[.*\]/, "")
```

then apply your RE to tmpstring

**correction:** made the match for brackets eager per nhahtd comment below, and also, made the RE global

```
string = "A bc defg hi [hi] jkl mnop."
tmpstring = string.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, "")
```

Comment: You need to make the `.*` lazy, i.e. `.*?`, otherwise, it will remove `[abc] should not remove [def]` from `text [abc] should not remove [def] text`

Answer (score 1):

Using only Regular Expressions, you can use:

```
hi(?!])
```

as an example.

Look here about negative lookahead: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html
Unfortunately, javascript does not support negative lookbehind.

I used http://regexpal.com/ to test, `abcd[hi]jkhilmnop` as test data, `hi(?!])` as the regex to find. It matched 'hi' without matching '[hi]'. Basically it matched the 'hi' so long as there was not a following ']' character.

This of course, can be expanded if needed. This has a benefit of not requiring any pre-processing for the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
r"\[(.*)\]"
```

Just play arounds with this if you wanto to use regular expressions.

Comment: This one I have played around with for quite a while.  However it returns two matches; hi and [hi].

With a "!" in front it returns 'hi' and 'hi'  So I tried to break the RE into two halves with a ! and still it returns both or none.

Answer (score 0):

This builds an array of all the strings contained in [ ]:

```
var regex = /\[([^\]]*)\]/;
var string = "A bc defg hi [hi] [jkl] mnop.";
var results=[], result;
while(result = regex.exec(string))
    results.push(result[1]);
```

**edit**

To answer to the question, this regex returns the string less all is in [ ], and trim whitespaces:

```
"A bc defg [hi] mnop [jkl].".replace(/(\s{0,1})\[[^\]]*\](\s{0,1})/g,'$1')
```

Comment: The OP wants to skip them, not match them.

Comment: he wants to skip the brackets from the result, but keep what is inside, this is what my code do.

Comment: ok, my bad. So this: "A bc defg hi [hi] [jkl] mnop.".replace(/\[[^\]]*\]/g,'') should do the job?

Comment: I think your regex will do the job (assuming the ``\`` are in the correct place) to remove the bracketed parts.

Comment: "A bc defg hi [hi] [jkl] mnop.".replace(/\\[[^\\]]*\\]/g,'')

Comment: "A bc defg hi [hi] [jkl] mnop.".replace(/\\s*\\[[^\\]]*\\]\\s*/g,' '), if you want to trim the spaces

Comment: Yes I am tying to skip the words in brackets.  Check the comments under Asad's answer to see exactly what I am going for.  But thank you both for the time and thought.

Answer (score 0):

What do yo uwant to do with it? If you want to selectively replace parts like "hi" except when it's "[hi]", then I often use a system where I match what I want to avoid first and then  what I want to watch; if it matches what I want to avoid then I return the match, otherwise I return the processed match.

Like this:

```
return string.replace(/(\[\w+\])|(\w+)/g, function(all, m1, m2) {return m1 || m2.toUpperCase()});
```

which, with the given string, returns:

```
"A BC DEFG HI [hi] JKL MNOP."
```

Thus: it replaces every word with uppercase (m1 is empty), except if the word is between square brackets (m1 is not empty).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of skipping the match you can probably try something different - match everything but do not ***capture*** the string within square brackets (inclusive) with something like this:

```
var r = /(?:\[.*?[^\[\]]\])|(.)/g;
var result;
var str = [];
while((result = r.exec(s)) !== null){
  if(result[1] !== undefined){ //true if [string] matched but not captured
    str.push(result[1]);
  }
}
console.log(str.join(''));
```

The last line will print parts of the string which do not match the `[string]` pattern. For example, when called with the input `"A [bc] [defg] hi [hi] j[kl]u m[no]p."` the code prints `"A   hi  ju mp."` with whitespaces intact.
You can try different things with this code e.g. replacing etc.